# PHP GET url param with dot in name

Tags: php

got something that appears not to work.  Say I have a url like

> www.test1.php?WC.id=12345

Then the following returns nothing

```
$_GET['WC.id'];
```

If I remove the WC. part, then it returns the 12345.  Can I not have a period within my url param name?

Thanks

Comment: Best advice, **avoid using dots (periods)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php#language.variables.external.dot-in-names):

> It is important to note that PHP will automatically replace any dots
>   in incoming variable names with underscores. [...] PHP irreversibly
>   modifies field names containing these characters in an attempt to
>   maintain compatibility with the deprecated register_globals feature.

> The full list of field-name characters that PHP converts to _
>   (underscore) is the following (not just dot):
>
> ```
> chr(32) ( ) (space)
> chr(46) (.) (dot)
> chr(91) ([) (open square bracket)
> chr(128) - chr(159) (various)
> ```

So, you can access to `WC.id` with `WC_id` name.

Answer (score 0):

If you get all your GET parameters with :

```
<?php
    var_dump($_GET);
?>
```

You will see a variable named : WC_id

```
array (size=1)
  'WC_id' => string '12345' (length=5)
```

So I think you need to get this parameter with :

```
<?php
    $WC_id = $_GET['WC_id']; // Here is your 12345
?>
```

Comment: His variable is named `WC.id`, and this is not allowed.

Comment: @nameless can you explain please, why this is not allowed ?

Comment: You shouldn't name variables with a dot in it, even if there are replaced by PHP, it's bad programming style in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a dot in URL for passing with `$_GET`. You can replace it by a `_`, this is readable better and you won't have any problems.

So it's `www.test1.php?WC_id=12345` and `$_GET['WC_id']`